# How to modify doc's v3 documentation macros à la doctools?

Tags: latex3, documentation, doc

I used the `ltxdoc` class with `doc` and `doctools` to document `prooftrees`. That documentation currently requires the compatibility option `doc2` as my modifications don't work with version 3 of `doc`.

I'm currently trying to document a new package in a similar style without the compatibility option. However, I cannot figure out how to change the way the names of macros, environments etc. are formatted in the margin by `\DescribeMacro`, `\DescribeEnv` etc.

I created a new command `\NewDocElements` to create new elements from a list and modify `\PrintDescribeWhatever` to do what I want. This seems to work all right (though the indexing probably needs work).

However, if I create a new element with `\NewDocElement` and then try to modify `\PrintDescribeWhatever`, it doesn't work. Moreover, `\RenewDocElement` doesn't have the effect I expect for macros and environments either.

Here's a minimal(ish) example:

```
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesFileSVN{$Id: somedoc.tex 9678 2023-08-12 05:33:06Z someauthor $}[some version \revinfo]
\GetFileInfoSVN*
\let\somedocdocversion\fileversion
\let\somedocdocbase\filebase
\let\somedocdocinfo\fileinfo
\let\somedocdocdate\filedate
% BEGIN preamble
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,parskip,kantlipsum}
\usepackage[%
  loadHyperref=true,
  createIndexEntries=false,
]{doctools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\val[1]{{\ttfamily = \meta{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\macrolabelfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\em\normalcolor}
\newcommand*\macrolabelname{macro}
\newcommand*\PrintLabelName[2][\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor]{#1#2}
\newcommand*\envlabelname{environment}
% \newcommand*\keylabelname{key}
\newcommand*\stylelabelname{style}
\def\somedoc@index#1#2{%doc.pdf v3 t15doc.pdf v3 t15
  \index{\doctools@indexHeadFont{#1s}!#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\keyname { s O {key} m }{%
  \texttt{#3}%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}{}{%
    \edef\tempa{\csname #2labelname\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\somedoc@index{\tempa}{#3}%
  }%
}
\RenewDocElement[% doc.pdf v3 t15
  macrolike = true ,
  toplevel = true,
  idxtype = macro,
  idxgroup = Macros,
  printtype = \macrolabelname{}
]{Macro}{macro}
\RenewDocElement[% doc.pdf v3 t15
  macrolike = false ,
  toplevel = true,
  idxtype = environment,
  idxgroup = Environments,
  printtype = \envlabelname{}
]{Env}{environment}
\NewDocElement[%
  macrolike = false,
  toplevel = true,
  idxtype = style,
  idxgroup = Styles,
  printtype = \stylelabelname{}
]{Style}{style}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \NewDocElements { s m } {
  \clist_set:Nn \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist
  {
    \NewDocElement[%
      macrolike = false,
      toplevel = true,
      idxtype = ##1,
      idxgroup = \text_titlecase:n {##1s},
      printtype = \csname ##1 labelname\endcsname
    ]{\text_titlecase:n {##1}}{##1}
    \IfBooleanF { #1 }
    {
      \ifcsdef { ##1 labelname } {
        \edef\tempa{Label~already~defined~for~##1}\show\tempa
      }{
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ##1 labelname \endcsname{ ##1 }
      }
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname PrintDescribe \text_titlecase:n {##1} \endcsname####1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
      \strut \MacroFont 
        \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} 
        \clist_map_inline:nn { ####1 }
        {
          ########1\par
        }
      \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\csname ##1 labelname\endcsname}
    }
  }
}
\def\PrintDescribeStyle#1{%
  \strut \MacroFont 
  \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} 
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    ##1\par
  }
  \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\csname ##1 labelname\endcsname}
}
\def\PrintDescribeMacro#1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
  \strut \MacroFont 
  \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} \string #1\par
  \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\macrolabelname}%
}
\def\PrintDescribeEnv#1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
  \strut \MacroFont 
  \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames}
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    ##1\par
  }
  \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\envlabelname}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocElements{colour,key}
\makeatother

\makeindex

% END preamble
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}\marg{something}\AfterLastParam
What \cs{mymacro} does.

\DescribeEnv{myenv,myotherenv}\oarg{something}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname[env]{myenv} and \keyname[env]{myotherenv} do.

\DescribeKey{mykey,myotherkey}\val{some value}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname{mykey} and \keyname{myotherkey} do.
\kant[1]

\DescribeColour{mycolour,myothercolour}
What \keyname[colour]{mycolour} and \keyname[colour]{myothercolour} do.
\kant[2]

\DescribeStyle{mystyle,myotherstyle}\val{key-value list}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname[style]{mystyle} and \keyname[style]{myotherstyle} do.

\end{document}
```

[image: mixed results]

The output I'd like is demonstrated by the cases of `key` and `colour`. The output I'm trying to change is demonstrated by the cases of `macro`, `env` and `style`. That is, for `env` and `style`, I'd like the different variants on different lines and for all three, I'd like the appropriate label (`macro`, `environment`, `style`) to be printed below the name(s).

I'm especially mystified `style` fails to work. I must be missing something obvious, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Just a cursory glance shows `doc` (re)defines `\PrintDescribeMacro` and `\PrintDescribeEnv` in the hook `begindocument/before` if `hyperref` is loaded (now the default, I think), which explains why defining them in the preamble has no effect

Comment: @mbert Thanks, but why does it work for `\NewDocElements`? I'm changing the same thing and also in the preamble. At least, I think I am.

Comment: I think it only `\def`'s those two, not the ones you create with `\NewDocElement`. I'm looking at the code block starting on line 907 of `doc.sty` starting with `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}[doc/hyperref]{%`

Comment: @mbert OK, thanks. I just looked and you're right. That's really helpful. But why doesn't it work for the `style` case? That's why that one particularly mystifies me. It seems to me I'm doing exactly the same for `style` as I do for `key` and `colour`, but I still don't get the label name below the name of the style. (Though it does put the variants on different lines.)

Comment: @mbert Never mind. I think I just realised what I've done ....

Comment: There's probably a good reason for it but the redefinition in `begindocument/before` seems surprising for the user and should at least be documented, I'd think

Comment: @mbert I agree. Especially since the documentation says `\RenewDocElement` can redefine existing doc elements. In fact, it says `So with doc version 3 modifications have to be done after the doc
package got loaded and the last modification will always win.` on page 17, which clearly suggests any time after loading should work. That's specifically in relation to `\PrintDescribeMacro`.

Comment: @mbert It's also far from easy to override the hook .... Anyway, do you want to answer?

Comment: Too busy at the moment so feel free to answer yourself. I think just wrapping the definitions in `\AtBeginDocument` should be enough

Comment: @mbert Done. If you want to post when you have time, I'll happily delete my answer and accept yours. Either way, thanks! This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @mbert (who doesn't have time to answer but suggested I do), I now have code which works.

There are actually at least two problems in my original code. The first is entirely my fault; the second is due to an undocumented (or under-documented?) feature of `doc.sty`.

The easy problem is to fix the `style` case:

```
  \def\PrintDescribeStyle#1{%
    \strut \MacroFont 
    \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} 
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
      ##1\par
    }
    \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\stylelabelname}
  }%
```

I'd originally got

```
  \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\csname ##1 labelname\endcsname}
```

which doesn't make sense, but didn't raise an error. `##1` isn't defined at this point because we've exited the loop and wouldn't have referred to the correct thing any way. `\csname ##1 labelname\endcsname` should just be `\stylelabelname`.

The second problem is specific to `macro` and `env`. Despite `doc`'s manual claiming macros such as `\PrintDescribeMacro` can be redefined after the package is loaded, they cannot effectively be redefined until `\begin{document}` if `hyperref` is loaded because, as mbert pointed out, `doc.sty` redefines them in the `begindocument/before` hook. This isn't the only thing it does at this point, but it is the most relevant here.

The solution is to modify these cases either after `\begin{document}` or in a hook. I tried to use `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}...` to do this, but I couldn't make that work. It does, however, work with a simple `\AtBeginDocument` (which is what mbert suggested in the first place).

[image: desired output]

```
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesFileSVN{$Id: somedoc.tex 9678 2023-08-12 05:33:06Z someauthor $}[some version \revinfo]
\GetFileInfoSVN*
\let\somedocdocversion\fileversion
\let\somedocdocbase\filebase
\let\somedocdocinfo\fileinfo
\let\somedocdocdate\filedate
% BEGIN preamble
\documentclass[]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox,kantlipsum,parskip}
\usepackage[%
  loadHyperref=true,
  createIndexEntries=false,
]{doctools}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\val[1]{{\ttfamily = \meta{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\macrolabelfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\em\normalcolor}
\newcommand*\macrolabelname{macro}
\newcommand*\PrintLabelName[2][\normalfont\normalsize\normalcolor]{#1#2}
\newcommand*\envlabelname{environment}
% \newcommand*\keylabelname{key}
\newcommand*\stylelabelname{style}
\def\somedoc@index#1#2{%doc.pdf v3 t15doc.pdf v3 t15
  \index{\doctools@indexHeadFont{#1s}!#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\keyname { s O {key} m }{%
  \texttt{#3}%
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}{}{%
    \edef\tempa{\csname #2labelname\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\somedoc@index{\tempa}{#3}%
  }%
}
\NewDocElement[%
  macrolike = false,
  toplevel = true,
  idxtype = style,
  idxgroup = Styles,
  printtype = \stylelabelname
]{Style}{style}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \NewDocElements { s m } {
  \clist_set:Nn \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__somedoc_doc_vals_clist
  {
    \NewDocElement[%
      macrolike = false,
      toplevel = true,
      idxtype = ##1,
      idxgroup = \text_titlecase:n {##1s},
      printtype = \csname ##1 labelname\endcsname
    ]{\text_titlecase:n {##1}}{##1}
    \IfBooleanF { #1 }
    {
      \ifcsdef { ##1 labelname } {
        \edef\tempa{Label~already~defined~for~##1}\show\tempa
      }{
        \expandafter\gdef\csname ##1 labelname \endcsname{ ##1 }
      }
    }
    \expandafter\def\csname PrintDescribe \text_titlecase:n {##1} \endcsname####1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
      \strut \MacroFont 
        \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} 
        \clist_map_inline:nn { ####1 }
        {
          ########1\par
        }
      \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\csname ##1 labelname\endcsname}
    }
  }
}
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument/before}{somedoc/hyperref}{after}{doc/hyperref}
% \AddToHook{begindocument/before}[somedoc/hyperref]
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocElement[% doc.pdf v3 t15
    macrolike = true ,
    toplevel = true,
    idxtype = macro,
    idxgroup = Macros,
    printtype = \macrolabelname
  ]{Macro}{macro}%
  \RenewDocElement[% doc.pdf v3 t15
    macrolike = false ,
    toplevel = true,
    idxtype = environment,
    idxgroup = Environments,
    printtype = \envlabelname
  ]{Env}{environment}%
  \def\PrintDescribeStyle#1{%
    \strut \MacroFont 
    \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} 
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
      ##1\par
    }
    \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\stylelabelname}
  }%
  \def\PrintDescribeMacro#1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
    \strut \MacroFont 
    \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames} \string #1\par
    \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\macrolabelname}%
  }%
  \def\PrintDescribeEnv#1{% addaswyd o doctools t18
    \strut \MacroFont 
    \color{doctools@ColorCodeNames}
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
      ##1\par
    }
    \PrintLabelName[\macrolabelfont] {\envlabelname}%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocElements{colour,key}
\makeatother

\makeindex
% \ShowHook{begindocument/before}
% END preamble
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}\marg{something}\AfterLastParam
What \cs{mymacro} does.

\DescribeEnv{myenv,myotherenv}\oarg{something}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname[env]{myenv} and \keyname[env]{myotherenv} do.

\DescribeKey{mykey,myotherkey}\val{some value}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname{mykey} and \keyname{myotherkey} do.
\kant[1]

\DescribeColour{mycolour,myothercolour}
What \keyname[colour]{mycolour} and \keyname[colour]{myothercolour} do.
\kant[2]

\DescribeStyle{mystyle,myotherstyle}\val{key-value list}\AfterLastParam
What \keyname[style]{mystyle} and \keyname[style]{myotherstyle} do.

\end{document}
```